# Working with Dictionary Values and Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def wordtally():
    test1 = "One day, Jimmy Jimmy Jimmy."
    no_punct = test1.strip(".")
    split = no_punct.split()
    subscript = 0
    D = {}
    split = no_punct.split()
    for n in split:
        if n in D.keys():
            D[n] += 1
        else:
            D[n] = 1
    return max(D.values())
```

My code right now returns the largest value, which is three, but I want it to return the key at which that value appears. When I try to use the key function, an error comes up that says it doesn't take any arguments. Is there a way to this?

Comment: You should change your conditional to `if n in D:` because at the moment you're generating a list of the keys and then check that list which is an `O(N)` operation. `n in D` is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the last line of your function to this:

```
return max(D.keys(), key=D.get) # or just D instead of D.keys()
```

It will return `Jimmy`.

`max` function will call [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get) `dict` method for each key in `D` in order to get the corresponding value and then return the key for the largest found value.

---

I hope you're aware of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.Counter). It can shorten your function:

```
from collections import Counter

def wordtally():
    test1 = "One day, Jimmy Jimmy Jimmy."
    no_punct = test1.strip(".")
    return Counter(no_punct.split()).most_common()[0][0]

print(wordtally()) # Jimmy
```

Comment: Can you explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple way for your question to get most common element in list:

```
def find_most_common(inStr,inSeperator):
    alist = inStr.strip(inSeperator).split()
    return max(set(alist), key=alist.count)

print find_most_commmon("One day, Jimmy Jimmy Jimmy.",".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an exercise, it'd be easier to use a `collections.Counter` to do the counting and `re.findall` to do a basic tokenisation of the words:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

text = 'One day, Jimmy Jimmy Jimmy.'
words = re.findall('\w+', text)
# ['One', 'day', 'Jimmy', 'Jimmy', 'Jimmy']
word_counts = Counter(words)
# Counter({'Jimmy': 3, 'day': 1, 'One': 1})
most_common, = word_counts.most_common(1)
# ('Jimmy', 3)
print most_common[0]
# Jimmy
```